# Data storage : cost of contract size?

Tags: storage

Ok so I'm trying to figure out how smart contracts work, excuse me if I'm missing something obvious.

Smart contracts are a type of account, and are thus stored on the blockchain state. My question concerns the size of the contract code itself. If my contract consist of 1 million lines, will these 1 millions lines be stored in the blockchain for free ?

As I understand it, only computation costs gas, not storage itself. What would prevent an ill-intentioned person to create lots of never-called contracts whith millions of arbitrary lines, just to overload the blockchain ?

Thanks !

Comment: Contract code **is** data.